# How to represent testfile name using regular expression in VB

Tags: vb.net

Newbie here. I have the following code in VB for reading csv file. Filename includes current date so it changes daily. How do I represent the filename using regular expression so it will read any csv file? Thanks

```
Dim objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\SEBCTS20220831.csv")
```

I have tried  -

```
        objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\^SEBCTS\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.csv$")
    'objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\^\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.csv$")
```

But I get an error -

Error: Could not find a part of the path '\FolderA\FolderB^SEBCTS\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w.csv$'.

Comment: Maybe `Dim fname = Path.Combine("\\FolderA\FolderB\", "SEBCTS" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & ".csv")` `Dim sr = IO.StreamReader(fname)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: The file you provide to the streamreader will need to be one single file, not a regex pattern.  If you want to do regex scanning, you will need to get a directory listing of e.g. all csv files, then loop over the list and identify the ones that match the regex.

Comment: @AndrewMorton how do I code it for files with dates in the past if I need to process an older file?

Comment: @jbpm Where does the required date come from?

Comment: @andrewmorton  Source system generated date

Comment: @andrewmorton Your code though worked for current dates so thank you very much

Comment: @jbpm If the source system generated date is a variable with the type DateTime, then in place of `DateTime.Now` you could use the name of the variable which contains the generated date.

Comment: Why try to guess what the file names are? Check out [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8) and [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Why you need regex, use `Date.TryParseExact` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
Dim file = "\\FolderA\FolderB\SEBCTS20220831.csv"
Dim fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
Dim format = "yyyyMMdd"
Dim possibleDate = If(fileName.Length >= format.Length, fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - format.Length), Nothing)
Dim parsedDate As Date
Dim isValidFile = Date.TryParseExact(possibleDate, format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, parsedDate)
```

If you not even want to ensure that the last digits of the file-name is a valid date but also today:

```
isValidFile = isValidFile AndAlso parsedDate.Date = Date.Today
```

Comment: Newbie here. Just trying out different things. Sorry for the confusion here. I meant reading any csv file using Streamreader

Comment: objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\SEBCTS20220831.csv")

Comment: Working on a SCriptTask in SSIS package to read CSV files and removing extra line feeds. I've got the removal of line feeds covered. I just need to be able to read any csv file. Which is why I was trying regular expressions. Thanks