# Regular Expression in filenames in VB

Tags: vb.net

Newbie here. Using StreamReader in VB, I am trying to read any csv file. Filename changes daily as it contains current date. Trying different Regular expressions to represent filename but with no luck.

My original line -

```
objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\SEBCTS20220831.csv")
```

I have tried -

```
    objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\^SEBCTS\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.csv$")
    objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\^\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.csv$")
```

But I got error - Error: Could not find a part of the path '\FolderA\FolderB^SEBCTS\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w.csv$'.

I also tried -

```
objReader = New IO.StreamReader("\\FolderA\FolderB\^SEBCTS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv$")
```

I get the error - Error: Could not find file '\FolderA\FolderB^SEBCTS[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv$'.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to represent testfile name using regular expression in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73818020/how-to-represent-testfile-name-using-regular-expression-in-vb)

Comment: If you don't like how you asked your question, edit the existing question, don't open a new one.